# reactfire React+firebase "contains an invalid key (.key) in property"

Tags: reactjs, firebase, reactfire

I get an error when trying to use update() or set()

My relevant code:

```
const ref = new Firebase('https://whatever.firebase.org/employees');
export default class EmployeeNew extends React.Component {
...
  this.update = () => {
    console.log(this.state, this.props.employee['.key']);
    ref.child(this.props.employee['.key']).set(this.state); // <-- no-dice
    // ref.update(this.state); <-- also fails.
  }
...
}
```

Output of console logs, when update is invoked as written above:

```
Object {avatar: "https://somevalue.png", name: "Bananaman", .key: "-KDObp8r82Ornrrmfbk5"}
Object "-KDObp8r82Ornrrmfbk5"
```

Error in browser console:

```
app.js:28366 Uncaught Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument  contains an invalid key (.key) in property 'employees.-KDObp8r82Ornrrmfbk5'.  Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"
```

Things i have tried:

```
  ref.update(this.state); // same error
  ref.update({this.props.employee['.key']: this.state}); // same error
```

Comment: I was able to achieve my intended result by hardcoding the new state object, essentially omitting the '.key'... There must be a better way tho.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve my intended result by hardcoding the new state object, essentially omitting the '.key'... There must be a better way tho. Open to suggestions. Thanks!

```
this.update = () => {
  let updatedEmployee = {avatar: this.state.avatar, name: this.state.name};
  ref.child(this.props.employee['.key']).set(updatedEmployee);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure there is a better way -- I kinda struggle to see why React Fire was designed like this. Anyway, are `this.state.name` and `this.state.avatar` objects or just simple values in firebase? Because if they are values, you should do `avatar: this.state.avatar['.value']`. But I guess you know that.